# Jasmine Mock for Angular service using promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following Angular service and mock/test setup.  I cannot get the mock http request to work properly.  I'm returning a promise from my factory and have the HTTP request mocked but the data in the controller's scope is not the data returned from the http service that the factory calls.

As you can see, I have called `$digest()` on `$rootScope` and `$httpBackend`.  I'm at a loss.

You can see from the fiddle that the code works properly and displays the text from the service, but the mock is not working.

Why?

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/gnxxbgy3/
Here is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
var ep = '/echo/json/';
myApp.factory('dataFactory', function($http) {
  var getData = function() {
    var data = $.param({
      json: JSON.stringify({
        name: "Name from Echo Service"
      })
    });
    return $http.post(ep, data);
  }

  return {
    getData: getData
  }
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, dataFactory) {
  $scope.name = 'Original Name';
  dataFactory.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.name = data.data.name;
  });
});

describe('Test For Site', function() {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));
  var $controller;
  var $httpBackend;
  var $q;
  var $rootScope;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$q_, _$rootScope_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $q = _$q_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  describe('test pageController', function() {
    it('Should pass', function() {
      var scope = {};
      $httpBackend.expect('POST', ep);
      $httpBackend.whenPOST(ep, function(str) {
        return true;
      }).respond(
        function() {
          return {
            name: "Name from Echo Service"
          };
        });
      var controller = $controller('MyCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
      });
      $httpBackend.flush();
      $rootScope.$digest();
      $rootScope.$flush();

      expect(scope.name).toBe('Name from Echo Service');
    });
  });
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was really minute problem, which took a lot to find it. `.whenPOST` of `$httpBackend` should only return `object/string` & your were returning a function which was returning by from `.respond` of `..whenPOST` method.

Just by returning plain JSON, rather than returning `function` solved the issue.

**Code**

```
$httpBackend.whenPOST(ep, function(str) {
    return true;
}).respond({
    name: "Name from Echo Service"
});
```

Also remove `$rootScope.$flush();` this line. `$rootScope` doesn't have `$flush` method in it.

[**Forked JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gnxxbgy3/24/)